# Access violation reading location 0x0000000c. VC++ and Dark GDK

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm developing a card game with Visual c++ (Visual studio 2008 Express Edition), DirectX SDK(August 2007) and Dark GDK.
I have carefully followed all the instructions while installing the softwares.

But while running any sample code i get this error "Access violation reading location 0x0000000c." and various dialogue boxes like "Failed to get device caps", "Failed to find valid stencil buffer", "Unable to create device", "Unable to setup 3D device"

I have carefully included the include and library files in VC++.

Please someone help me to get rid of this problem

```
#include "DarkGDK.h"
void DarkGDK ( void )
{
dbSyncOn ( );
dbSyncRate ( 60 );
dbCreateAnimatedSprite ( 1, "animatedsprite.png", 4, 4, 1 );
while ( LoopGDK ( ) )
{
    dbPasteSprite ( 1, 0, 0 );
    dbPlaySprite ( 1, 1, 16, 200 );
    dbSync ( );
}
return;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings during compilation?

Comment: Verify that your system complies with the [system requirements](http://www.thegamecreators.com/?m=view_product&id=2128&page=system). It sounds as if your display hardware doesn't.

Comment: An access violation such as this generally indicates a function  expecting to return a valid pointer (most likely as a handle of some sort) returned NULL instead. The handle/pointer is then either directly accessed or passed on to another function that accesses a member (in this case 12 bytes deep into the structure). **Check your return values before invoking the next API call.**

Comment: See this is my sample program that i was talking about:- #include "DarkGDK.h"
void DarkGDK ( void )
{
 dbSyncOn ( );
 dbSyncRate ( 60 );
 dbCreateAnimatedSprite ( 1, "animatedsprite.png", 4, 4, 1 );
 while ( LoopGDK ( ) )
 {
  dbPasteSprite ( 1, 0, 0 );
  dbPlaySprite ( 1, 1, 16, 200 );
  dbSync ( );
 }
 return;
}

Comment: i'm getting access violation at dbCreateAnimatedSprite ( 1, "animatedsprite.png", 4, 4, 1 );

Comment: Edit the *question*. Please don't post code of this magnitude in a comment.

Comment: @Shahbaz i'm not getting any warnings during compilation

Comment: i have posted my program in the question

Comment: The most common causes of those problems seem to be either missing graphics drivers or running on a virtual machine. Have you searched the Dark GDK forums?

Comment: yes, i have searched on the dark gdk forums...i'm not on a virtual machine and my graphics drivers are working fine